# Why Moq verify method call throws exception?

Tags: f#, moq

I can't get this piece of code to pass.

```
[<Test>]
member public this.Test() =
    let mock = new Mock<IList<string>>()
    let mockObj = mock.Object

    mockObj.Add("aaa")        
    mock.Verify(fun m -> m.Add(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once())
```

Exception I get:

```
System.ArgumentException : Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit'
```

I believe it has something to do with F# not inferring properly the data type of labda expression but I don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, this an issue with F# type inference when calling an overloaded method that accepts either Action or Func.

One option is to download the [Moq.FSharp.Extensions](http://trelford.com/blog/post/MoqEx.aspx) from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq.FSharp.Extensions/) and change your `Verify` to an explicit `VerifyAction`, i.e.

```
open Moq.FSharp.Extensions

type MyTests() = 
    [<Test>]
    member public this.Test() =
        let mock = new Mock<IList<string>>()
        let mockObj = mock.Object       
        mockObj.Add("aaa")        
        mock.VerifyAction((fun m -> m.Add(any())), Times.Once())
```

Underneath the covers the Moq.FSharp.Extensions simply defines an extension method `VerifyAction` that only takes an `Action` to avoid ambiguity:

```
type Moq.Mock<'TAbstract> when 'TAbstract : not struct with
    member mock.VerifyAction(expression:Expression<Action<'TAbstract>>) =
        mock.Verify(expression)
```

Another option is to use [Foq](http://foq.codeplex.com/), a mocking library with a similar API to Moq but designed specifically for use from F#, also available via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Foq):

```
[<Test>]
member public this.Test() =
    let mock = Mock.Of<IList<string>>()           
    mock.Add("aaa")        
    Mock.Verify(<@ mock.Add(any()) @>, once)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I wonder though if I can explicitly specify overload that I want to use?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not currently aware of a way of explicitly specifying that overload, if you don't want to pull in Moq.FSharp.Extensions you could just pull in the type extension to Moq in the middle of the answer